# Understand np.mean in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to understand how np.mean is working in the following example:

```
n = np.array([1,7,5,4])
m = pd.Series(data = [1,2,3,4],index = [1,2,3,4])

print(np.mean(n!=m))
## returns 0.5
print(np.mean(n[n!=m]))
## returns 4.0
```

could someone explain how the first output is working out the value 0.5 and how np.mean is treating the boolean series n!=m? I understand what the second part is doing

Comment: Look into NumPy boolean indexing for the second part and boolean arrays for the first part.

Comment: True is 1, and False is 0: n!=m is 1    False, 2     True, 3     True, 4    False then mean is (False + True + True + False)/4 = (0 + 1 + 1+ 0)/4 = 0.5, but  n[n!=m] is n[(False, True, True, False)] = n[(0, 1, 1, 0)] = [1, 7, 7, 1] then mean is (1+7+7+1)/4 = 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

n !=m returns a boolean array .True and False values are treated as 1,0 respectively. In this case (0+1+1,0)/4 yields 0.5

```
>>> n != m
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
```

dtype: bool

> > > n[n!=m]
> > >       array([1, 7, 7, 1])

it means applying boolean selection on 'n'. it returns the [1,7,7,1]/4  yields 4

```
>>> condition = [n !=m]
>>> condition
[1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool]
>>> n[condition]
array([1, 7, 7, 1])
```